# JavaScript live grade Calculator

Tags: javascript, beginner, html5

Worth noting:
I cannot use any languages other than HTML5 and JavaScript (no JQuery!).
Grade calculator needs to update live.
Grade calculator needs to show a percentage grade based off score obtained/score possible AND a letter grade.
I've been at this for three days.  Please help me, and if possible, please explain why my code doesn't work, or why the solution does vs. mine, so that I can learn.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Grade Calculator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="styles.css">
    <link rel="javascript" href="script.js">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>SAIT Grade Calculator</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="wrapper">
        <h1> Grade Calculator </h1>

        <input type="text" id= "enumerator" onkeyup="setGrades();" />
        <input type= "text" id = "denominator" onkeyup="setGrades();"/>


        <h2>Your Percentage Grade </h2>
            <p>Your percentage grade is: </p>
        <input type="text" id="percentgrade">
        <h2>Your Letter Grade </h2>
        <p>Your letter grade is: </p>
        <input type="text" id="letter">


    </main>
<script>
    function setGrades (){
     var gradeobtained = 
parseFloat(document.getElementById('enumerator').value);
    var gradepossible = 
parseFloat(document.getElementById('denominator').value);



        var numbergrade = (gradeobtained / gradepossible)*100) ; 
document.getElementById('total').value = numbergrade;
var percentscore = 
if (numbergrade>=101) {
document.getElementById("percentgrade").innerHTML = "Sorry, it is not 
possible to have a grade over 100%"
}
else {
document.getElementById("percentgrade").innerHTML = numbergrade.value
};



    var lettergrade = if(numbergrade >= 90){
        document.getElementById('letter').value = "A+";
    }

    else if(89 >= numbergrade && numbergrade >= 85){
        document.getElementById('letter').value = "A";
    }

    else if(84 >= numbergrade && numbergrade >= 80){
        document.getElementById('letter').value = "A-";
    }

    else if(79 >= numbergrade && numbergrade >= 76){
        document.getElementById('letter').value = "B+";
    }

    else if(75 >= numbergrade && numbergrade >= 73){
        document.getElementById('letter').value = "B";
    }

    else if(72 >= numbergrade && numbergrade >= 70){
        document.getElementById('letter').value = "B-";
    }

    else if(69 >= numbergrade && numbergrade >= 66){
        document.getElementById('letter').value = "C+";
    }

    else if(65 >= numbergrade && numbergrade >= 63){
        document.getElementById('letter').value = "C";
    }

else if(62 >= numbergrade && numbergrade >= 60){
document.getElementById('letter').value = "C-";
}

else if(59 >= numbergrade && numbergrade >= 55){
document.getElementById('letter').value = "D+";
}
else if(54 >= numbergrade && numbergrade >= 50){
document.getElementById('letter').value = "D";
}
else{
document.getElementById('letter').value = "F";
}
} ;

</script>
<footer>© Nicole  2017</footer>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! Here we review only code that works already as intended and we strive to make this code better. Questions asking to fix broken code are off-topic. Have a look at the [help/on-topic] to learn more about what is on-/ and off-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Does the code function correctly?  If not, it isn't ready for Code Review (see [help/on-topic]) and the question may be deleted.

Comment: my apologies, this code IS broken, and may be deleted in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, there's an error in the code you've written which will prevent the calculator from working correctly:

```
document.getElementById('total').value = numbergrade;
```

You don't have an element with the ID of `total` so this will fail. I'm guessing you want to change this ID to `percentgrade`.

You also have invalid syntax here:

```
var percentscore =
if (numbergrade>=101) {
```

You need to assign a value to `percentscore` if you put an `=` sign after it. You're actually not using it in the rest of the code so you can get rid of the variable completely.

---

Next it can be cleaned up a bit. `if (numbergrade >= 101)` is a little unclear, compared to the shorter and simpler `if (numbergrade > 100)`. The number 100 has meaning for a test because it's the maximum grade. The number 101 doesn't it's simply an invalid value. You could also extract this out into a variable to assign an even stronger meaning.

```
var MAX_OBTAINABLE = 100;

if (numbergrade > MAX_OBTAINABLE) {
```

Note the capital casing to indicate a constant. In more modern iterations of javascript you can actually create a true constant by using the `const` keyword rather than `var` or `let`

```
const MAX_OBTAINABLE = 100;
```

---

The next part which needs to be changed is your rendering of the values. Your `percentgrade` element is a textbox, so you should be setting it's value property. Currently you are setting the innerHTML which won't work.

```
document.getElementById("percentgrade").innerHTML =
```

Should become

```
document.getElementById("percentgrade").value =
```

---

The last part where you calculate the grade letter, could also do with some improvements. Whenever you find yourself using the same calculated more than once or twice, it becomes a good candidate to store in a variable. In this case, you've written `document.getElementById('letter')` many times. You can shorten in by extracting it into a variable before you start to determine the grade letter

```
var letterDisplay = document.getElementById('letter');

if (numbergrade >= 90) {
    letterDisplay.value = 'A+';
}
else if (89 >= numbergrade && numbergrade >= 85){
    letterDisplay.value = "A";
}

// ... etcetera
```

On this first line you've also attempted to assign the variable `lettergrade` to an `if` statement which is invalid syntax.

var lettergrade = if(numbergrade >= 90) {

You don't seem to be using this variable so you *could* get rid of this assignment. However, you could actually use that variable to make the above code even shorter. Starting off with the letter grade set to `F` we can do the following:

```
var letterDisplay = document.getElementById('letter');
var lettergrade = 'F';

if (numbergrade >= 90) {
    lettergrade = "A+";
}
else if (89 >= numbergrade && numbergrade >= 85) {
    lettergrade = "A";
}

// .... all the other if statements here.

else if (54 >= numbergrade && numbergrade >= 50) {
    lettergrade = 'D';
}

letterDisplay.value = lettergrade;
```

There are some more ways you could improve on this, but that's a few of the basic, for some slightly more advanced concepts like objects, functions and looping, take a look at this [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vat357wk/) I created and have a play around

Comment: [Or better yet](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/abb67a5573bcd51c262d007adf71ad50)